# Parsing a file, build succeeds but error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

everybody I've been running into this problem with my homework for awhile. I tried to get help but was answered with "I can't help". The assignment is to parse a file and calculate the given shapes perimeter or area. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> parseString(string); // prototype

int main()
{
  ifstream fin;
  string str;

  fin.open("Shapes.input.txt");

  while(!fin.eof())
  {
    std::getline(fin,str);
    vector<string> tokens = parseString(str);
    cout << tokens[0];
  }
  fin.close();
}


vector<string> parseString(string str)
{
  stringstream s(str);
  istream_iterator<string> begin(s), end;
  return vector<string>(begin, end);
}
```

The code will successfully build but I get an error for: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am not sure how to debug this. I will include the data I made in the file as well to test this portion.

SQUARE 5
SQUARE 7

Sorry if this is a lengthy post, it is my first time posting and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your loop is wrong. the last `getline` will fail. Read this: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Related, your code assumes a vector with at least one token, an assertion you should probably check before blindly assuming it via `operator[]` on that vector.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The post is of reasonable length.  Congratulations on actually posting a [mcve], including the input data - that's a lot more than most people manage.  I suggest reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Incidentally, this is an excellent example of why `using namespace std` is a bad idea.  It's not obvious (to a reader) when you write `vector<string>(begin, end);` whether you mean the local variables `begin`, `end`, or the library functions `std::begin`, `std::end`.  That makes it harder to read your code.

Comment: thank you everyone, I changed my code but my code still does not read the file, it may have something to do with @WhozCraig 's comment. This is what the code contains right now:                                                                            ifstream fin;
    string str;
    
    fin.open("Shapes.input.txt");
    
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
       while(fin >> str)
       {
           fin >> str;
           vector<string> tokens = parseString(str);
        
           //test output
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           cout << tokens[i];
       }
    }